# ie8 -> ie9 upgrade and x-ua

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a corporate app with ie8 as the current forced browser.  Machines are locked down tight and i can't even test on anything else because I can't install anything else.  There are no other version of ie in use.  it is 100% ie8.  no 7, no 9.  And they default to run in ie 7 compat / ie8 quirks mode.

In order to get stuff working right and to force standards mode, i had to use the html 5 DTD (to future-ready the site for mobile dev coming down the pipe instead of xhtml4) and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

heading in the template.

I have no information when they might go to ie9... or even skip to ie10.

Whats the best way to future proof this intranet site without being able to test it in ie9 or ie10, or a gecko browser?
I tried to follow tight standards and keep it clean with jquery and css and no in-line markup.

What does an ie9 do when it sees the ie=8 x-ua header?  Should i use something else instead of this?  I may not be working this app when the move comes.   What notes should I leave for a future developer to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the X-UA-Compatible set to IE=8. IE9 and IE10 will try to switch to IE8 mode.

Comment: Is that wrong, for ie9/10 though?  would that degrade them down, holding back future capabilites of their borwsers?

Comment: Well, it's not wrong. It is the purpose of X-UA-Compatible. It has it in its name. It will hold back future capabilities of new browsers to ensure the web page will look the same as in IE8. E.g. you can not use html5 canvas when browser mode is IE8.

Comment: You can try different browser modes in your IE. Just press F12 and the developer tools will appear. Then switch browser mode.